# UWP change ComboBox position when opening

Tags: c#, combobox, win-universal-app

I have a `ComboBox` in c# XAML and when nothing is selected and the `PlaceHolderText` is shown and I click on it to open, the normal behavior is to open it in the middle.

I want the dropdown to open on top instead. Let's say I have a `ComboBox` and fill it with the number **1-100**, then I want it to display beginning from **1**. If there are seven items shown in the dropdown, then the numbers **1-7** should be visible. Normal behavior would be showing the numbers **47-53**.

An old workaround would be using a `ListView`, but I don't want this.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What about this workaround?

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace StackOverFlowSampleApp
{
    public class ExtendedComboBox : ComboBox
    {
        private ScrollViewer _scrollViewer;

        public ExtendedComboBox()
        {
            DefaultStyleKey = typeof(ComboBox);
        }

        protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();
            _scrollViewer = GetTemplateChild("ScrollViewer") as ScrollViewer;
            if (_scrollViewer != null)
            {
                _scrollViewer.Loaded += OnScrollViewerLoaded;
            }
        }

        private void OnScrollViewerLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _scrollViewer.Loaded -= OnScrollViewerLoaded;
            _scrollViewer.ChangeView(null, 0, null);
        }
    }
}
```

How it works before:

[image]

How it works after workaround:

[image]